# In a Win32 ListView I have both regular and state icons. This works on Win7, but not on XP

Tags: windows, winapi, listview, icons, virtual

I have looked at the Microsoft documentation but it says that there should be no difference.

Note that this is a virtual ListView, so I supply the state icon index in the code implementing the LVN_GETDISPINFO message, if the LVIF_STATE flag is set in LV_ITEM::mask.

Does anyone know of any subtle differences which may cause this difference in behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Not posting any sample code in your question does not exactly help...

This code works for me:

[image]

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "comctl32.lib")

typedef struct {
    LPTSTR text;
    UINT icon;
    UINT stateicon;
} MYITEM;
HWND g_hLV=NULL;
MYITEM g_myitems[2]={{"item1",0,0},{"item2",2,2}};

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd,UINT msg,WPARAM wp,LPARAM lp) 
{
    switch(msg) 
    {
    case WM_NOTIFY:
        if (lp) 
        {
            NMLVDISPINFO*pLVDI=(NMLVDISPINFO*)lp;
            NMLISTVIEW*&pLV=(NMLISTVIEW*&)pLVDI;
            switch(pLVDI->hdr.code) 
            {
            case LVN_GETDISPINFO:
                if (LVIF_TEXT&pLVDI->item.mask) pLVDI->item.pszText=g_myitems[pLVDI->item.iItem].text;
                if (LVIF_IMAGE&pLVDI->item.mask) pLVDI->item.iImage=g_myitems[pLVDI->item.iItem].icon;
                if (LVIF_STATE&pLVDI->item.mask) 
                {
                    pLVDI->item.state=INDEXTOSTATEIMAGEMASK(1+g_myitems[pLVDI->item.iItem].stateicon);
                    pLVDI->item.stateMask=pLVDI->item.state;
                }
                return 0;
            }
        }
        break;
    case WM_CREATE:
        {
            g_hLV=CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,WC_LISTVIEW,0,WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD|LVS_OWNERDATA|LVS_REPORT|LVS_SHAREIMAGELISTS,0,0,0,0,hwnd,0,0,0);
            LVCOLUMN lvc={LVCF_TEXT|LVCF_WIDTH};
            lvc.pszText="dummy";
            lvc.cx=99;
            ListView_InsertColumn(g_hLV,0,&lvc);
            SHFILEINFO sfi;
            HIMAGELIST hil=(HIMAGELIST)SHGetFileInfo(".\\",FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY,&sfi,0,SHGFI_SMALLICON|SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX|SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES);
            ListView_SetImageList(g_hLV,hil,LVSIL_SMALL);
            ListView_SetImageList(g_hLV,hil,LVSIL_STATE);
            g_myitems[1].stateicon=g_myitems[1].icon=sfi.iIcon;//assuming the imagelist has icons is wrong, so set at least one of them to a valid index
            ListView_SetCallbackMask(g_hLV,LVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK);
            ListView_SetItemCount(g_hLV,2);
        }
        return 0;
    case WM_SIZE:
        SetWindowPos(g_hLV,0,0,0,LOWORD(lp),HIWORD(lp),SWP_NOZORDER|SWP_NOACTIVATE);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd,msg,wp,lp);
}

int WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,LPSTR lpCmdLine,int nShowCmd) 
{
    InitCommonControls();
    //This dialog subclassing is a ugly hack, but this is just sample code!
    HWND hwnd=CreateWindowEx(0,WC_DIALOG,"LVTest",WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,0,0,99,99,0,0,0,0);
    SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd,GWLP_WNDPROC,(LONG_PTR)WndProc);
    SendMessage(hwnd,WM_CREATE,0,0);
    ShowWindow(hwnd,nShowCmd);
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg,0,0,0) > 0) 
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Anders for your great effort. I was however asking if anyone had had the same problem as I did, so I could use their solution for my case. 
The reason for not showing the code is its sheer size. I am using the wxWidgets library which hides the ListCtrl in a class, but does not implement state icons. So I have my own message handler which intercepts the LVN_GETDISPINFO message and adds the state image index. Of course this is risky business but I was really happy when it worked just fine on Win7. 
So that's the background for posing the question in the way that I did...

Comment: @Bengt: Are you calling ListView_SetCallbackMask etc?