# Can not assign different Icons in Win32 ImageList only one Icon is being shown

Tags: c++, c, listview, winapi

I am working on a project that uses Win32 listview to arrange and visualize some data and files. And I would like to add different kind of icons to the list items along with their names. I have seen screenshots of many applications that has different kind of icons assigned to it and mine one , with no icons , looks very much odd and old styled.

I tried the example code from [Microsoft's official page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/add-list-view-image-lists) which was supposed to add different icons into imagelists.I then tried to assign the imagelist to my listbox but unfortunately , only one of the icons is being assigned to all the other items and other icons are being completely ignored.

[image: App]

As you can see in the screenshot, the parent window has the ***IDI_NETWORK*** icon which means our resource files has successfully been configured by my application. But the problem is...
Even after adding this code from [Microsoft's official site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/add-list-view-image-lists) in my application to insert icons, the function ***InitListViewImageLists*** assigns the same icon to all the items in the listview.

```
BOOL InitListViewImageLists(HWND hWndListView) 
{ 
    int index=0;
    HICON hIconItem;     // Icon for list-view items.
    HIMAGELIST hLarge;   // Image list for icon view.
    HIMAGELIST hSmall;   // Image list for other views.

    // Create the full-sized icon image lists. 
    hLarge = ImageList_Create(32, 
                              32, 
                              ILC_COLOR32, 1, 1); 

    hSmall = ImageList_Create(32, 
                              32, 
                              ILC_COLOR32, 1, 1); 
    
    // Add an icon to each image list.  
    /*hiconItem = LoadIcon(g_hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ITEM));

    ImageList_AddIcon(hLarge, hiconItem);
    ImageList_AddIcon(hSmall, hiconItem);

    DestroyIcon(hiconItem);*/
 
// When you are dealing with multiple icons, you can use the previous four lines of 
// code inside a loop. The following code shows such a loop. The 
// icons are defined in the application's header file as resources, which 
// are numbered consecutively starting with IDS_FIRSTICON. The number of 
// icons is defined in the header file as C_ICONS.
   
    for(index = 0; index < 5; index++)
    {
        hIconItem = LoadIcon (GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MALE+index));
        ImageList_AddIcon(hSmall, hIconItem);
        ImageList_AddIcon(hLarge, hIconItem);
        DestroyIcon(hIconItem);
    }

    
    // Assign the image lists to the list-view control. 
    ListView_SetImageList(hWndListView, hLarge, LVSIL_NORMAL); 
    ListView_SetImageList(hWndListView, hSmall, LVSIL_SMALL); 
    
    return TRUE; 
}
```

you can see in the screenshot that the listview items only have ***IDI_FEMALE*** icon assigned ignoring rest of the icons.

```
for(index = 0; index < 5; index++)
    {
        hIconItem = LoadIcon (GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MALE+index));
        ImageList_AddIcon(hSmall, hIconItem);
        ImageList_AddIcon(hLarge, hIconItem);
        DestroyIcon(hIconItem);
    }
```

This code in function ***InitListViewImageLists*** was supposed to add add all the icons but unfortunately this is only assgning only one icon that is ***IDI_FEMALE***

***I am leaving my codes below***

Contents of ***resource.rc***

```
#include "resource.h"
IDI_MALE ICON "male.ico"
IDI_FEMALE ICON "female.ico"
IDI_NETWORK ICON "net.ico"
IDI_WIFI ICON "wifi.ico"
IDI_TRANS ICON "trans.ico"
```

Contents of ***resource.h***

```
#define IDI_MALE 1
#define IDI_FEMALE 2
#define IDI_TRANS 3
#define IDI_WIFI 4
#define IDI_NETWORK 5
```

***Compiled into resource.rs and is being used in my application***

***My Application code***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include "resource.h"


HWND Wmain , ListView;

char col[][255] = {"Filename","Size"};






// InitListViewImageLists: Creates image lists for a list-view control.
// This function only creates image lists. It does not insert the items into
// the control, which is necessary for the control to be visible.   
//
// Returns TRUE if successful, or FALSE otherwise. 
//
// hWndListView: Handle to the list-view control. 
// global variable g_hInst: The handle to the module of either a 
// dynamic-link library (DLL) or executable (.exe) that contains
// the image to be loaded. If loading a standard or system
// icon, set g_hInst to NULL.
//
BOOL InitListViewImageLists(HWND hWndListView) 
{ 
    int index=0;
    HICON hIconItem;     // Icon for list-view items.
    HIMAGELIST hLarge;   // Image list for icon view.
    HIMAGELIST hSmall;   // Image list for other views.

    // Create the full-sized icon image lists. 
    hLarge = ImageList_Create(32, 
                              32, 
                              ILC_COLOR32, 1, 1); 

    hSmall = ImageList_Create(32, 
                              32, 
                              ILC_COLOR32, 1, 1); 
    
    // Add an icon to each image list.  
    /*hiconItem = LoadIcon(g_hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ITEM));

    ImageList_AddIcon(hLarge, hiconItem);
    ImageList_AddIcon(hSmall, hiconItem);

    DestroyIcon(hiconItem);*/
 
// When you are dealing with multiple icons, you can use the previous four lines of 
// code inside a loop. The following code shows such a loop. The 
// icons are defined in the application's header file as resources, which 
// are numbered consecutively starting with IDS_FIRSTICON. The number of 
// icons is defined in the header file as C_ICONS.
   
    for(index = 0; index < 5; index++)
    {
        hIconItem = LoadIcon (GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MALE+index));
        ImageList_AddIcon(hSmall, hIconItem);
        ImageList_AddIcon(hLarge, hIconItem);
        DestroyIcon(hIconItem);
    }

    
    // Assign the image lists to the list-view control. 
    ListView_SetImageList(hWndListView, hLarge, LVSIL_NORMAL); 
    ListView_SetImageList(hWndListView, hSmall, LVSIL_SMALL); 
    
    return TRUE; 
}


void LV_addColumns(HWND hwnd , char name[] , char size[]){
    LVCOLUMN lvc; 
    lvc.mask = LVCF_FMT | LVCF_WIDTH | LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_SUBITEM;
    
    
    
    
    int counter=0;
    

    
    
    
    
    lvc.iSubItem = counter++;
    lvc.pszText = (LPSTR)name;
    lvc.cx = 200;
    lvc.fmt = LVCFMT_LEFT;
    ListView_InsertColumn(hwnd, counter, &lvc);
    
    lvc.iSubItem = counter;
    lvc.pszText = (LPSTR)size;
    lvc.cx = 200;
    lvc.fmt = LVCFMT_LEFT;
    ListView_InsertColumn(hwnd, counter, &lvc);
    
}

void AddLVItem(HWND hwnd , int index,char Name[] , char Size[]){
    
    LVITEM lvi;
    
    int x=0;
        
    lvi.mask=  LVIF_TEXT | LVIF_IMAGE;

    lvi.iItem=index; //cRecord is raised 1 before every function call 
    lvi.iImage = 1;
    lvi.iSubItem=0;
    
    lvi.pszText=(LPSTR)"1";
    SendMessage(hwnd, LVM_INSERTITEM, 0, (LPARAM) &lvi);

//Add Subitems from a structur


    
    
    lvi.iSubItem=0;
    lvi.pszText=(LPSTR)Name;
    lvi.mask = LVIF_TEXT  | LVIF_STATE  ;
    SendMessage(hwnd, LVM_SETITEM, 0,(LPARAM) &lvi);  
    
    
    lvi.iSubItem=1;
    lvi.pszText=(LPSTR)Size;
    lvi.mask = LVIF_TEXT  | LVIF_STATE  ;
    SendMessage(hwnd, LVM_SETITEM, 0,(LPARAM) &lvi);  

}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd , UINT Msg , WPARAM wParam , LPARAM lParam){
    
    switch(Msg){
        
        case WM_DESTROY: {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        }
        case WM_CREATE: {
            
        ListView=   CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,  WC_LISTVIEW, NULL,    LVS_REPORT |  WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD | LVS_ICON  , 0, 0, 400, 500, hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
            LV_addColumns(ListView,(char*)"FileName",(char*)"Size");
            AddLVItem(ListView,0,(char*)"AudioFile",(char*)"3GB");
            AddLVItem(ListView,1,(char*)"ImageFile",(char*)"10MB");
            AddLVItem(ListView,2,(char*)"VideoFile",(char*)"100MB");
            AddLVItem(ListView,3,(char*)"TextFile",(char*)"300B");
            InitListViewImageLists(ListView);
            break;
        }
        
        
        case WM_COMMAND: {
            
            break;
        }
        
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd,Msg,wParam,lParam);
        
    }
    
    return 0;
}


/* Below are the codes for parent Window (WinMain) that have not been provided here to keep the code short and more readable */
```

After more googling ...
I further tried codes from [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/381331/Insert-icons-in-ListView-WIN-32) and [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967115/in-a-win32-listview-i-have-both-regular-and-state-icons-this-works-on-win7-but) but I dont seem to have luck.

Now how can I achieve something like this ? This is what I want.

[image]

I have been trying to figure it out since the day before yesterday but I think I am in need of some advices from the experienced community. The compilers I am using are ***gcc*** and ***g++*** (MinGW on Windows 10).Please provide a working source code along with a good explanation . A working source code will make it easier for me to understand my errors.

Thank You So Much!

Comment: Should `lvi.iImage = 1;` be `lvi.iImage = index;`?  Also, `index` is a poor choice of name.

Comment: This worked Thanks ! can you please post this as an answer so that I can tick it.

Comment: On a side note: don't call `DestroyIcon()` on an `HICON` returned by `LoadIcon()`. The documentation for `ImageList_AddIcon()` and `LoadIcon()` say as much.